# What are the consequences of having a full partition on a Linux system?

Tags: linux, partitioning

This may sound like a stupid question, but bear with me.

*What bad things could happen to your system if a partition was full?*

I know intuitively that it's a bad thing and you should avoid it. However, I was talking to someone not as comfortable with computers, and I had a hard time explaining *why* it was a bad thing. Obviously, you can't create files in a full partition, but are there additional consequences?

Comment: Tell to that someone "Is it bad, if I fill your room completely with junk to the point that you can't move anywhere from wherever you are standing?" ... If it is bad, that is how your PC feels when you fill up the HDD completely. The 'imaginary' magic number is about 5-10% of free HDD space (Note: Imaginary - no scientific proof or background knowledge on this whatsoever.. unless someone can provide proof to make this real)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've had this happen on a backup server (which also ran a small web server) that – instead of writing to a networked share – would simply write to `/mnt/backup`, thinking it was pointing to our NAS. Instead, it was writing to the local machine, quickly filling it up the smallish server drive with 50 GB of backups.

First off, the machine will just feel slow, because reading and writing data takes longer.

What you'll soon start to notice is that the web server cannot serve any pages that require database access, because MySQL can't properly serve anymore. This is because it also needs to *write* data.

You'll get really cryptic error messages from all kinds of programs, because no process will be able to write anything anymore. And since not all programs are that verbose when something fails, you'll be left guessing what the real issue with your system is until you type in `df -h`.

The good thing is that, at least with `ext` filesystems, the `root` user gets 5% of space reserved, so you can still log into the system remotely via SSH, even if it's 95% full. Just imagine… if that weren't the case, any unprivileged user could kill a system by filling it up completely. Once you're logged in as root, you could forcefully remove files to free up some space.

See also:

- [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)